# .Net - Google Play Download Sales Reports

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-play-developer-api

I have a .Net Core application attempting to download the latest sales reports from my Google Play account to view and track sales statistics. These reports are stored on a Google Cloud Storage bucket "owned"/managed by the Google Play Store.

I've been unable to find many other examples or related issues in .Net and have been experiencing a storage permission issue.

I'm following the rather limited guide here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export under "Download reports using a client library and service account"

**Step 1:** Create a service account
I've created a new service account for a new project as shown below. I've also granted that service account permissions for all storage objects as shown.
[image]

**Step 2:** Add the service account on your play console
I've also invited this new service account user to my play console and granted it permissions to the app to view it's information and financial reports.
[image]

[image]

**Step 3:** Fetch reports using an API call
I've created and downloaded a .JSON key for the service user.

```
// Scope as specified in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only" };
// Import JSON credential
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "keys/googleplay.json")).CreateScoped(scopes);

// Bucket ID of Google Play Store - Found from reports page "Copy URL"
string bucketId = "pubsite_prod_5XXXXXXXXX2";
var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);

var bucketObjects = storage.ListObjects(bucketId);
foreach (var bucketObject in bucketObjects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bucketObject.Name);
}
```

This results in a permission error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nsupportapp-googleplay@ascendant-nova-300105.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[supportapp-googleplay@ascendant-nova-300105.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The service account I've created has the `storage.objects.list` permission and has been invited to my Play Console as well (as shown in the screenshots). This is a storage bucket hosted/owned by Google Play and not me. How can this permissions issue be resolved to allow my linked account to access Google Play's sales reports via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back in the morning and magically things now work.
I have also changed to using `fromStream` instead of `fromFile` when creating the Google credential.

Changed:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only" };
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "keys/googleplay.json")).CreateScoped(scopes);
```

To:

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "keys/googleplay.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
}
```

However, both of these credential creation systems work just fine... Perhaps it took Google 12 hours to sync the permissions? Hopefully this example can help someone else out in the future.

Comment: Hi Brian. your answer and question have valuable information for my project, now I am expecting that in some hours I will be able to download the reports!