# Downloading google play store reports programmatically using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to download google play console reports using python [[source]](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-client-library-and-service-account). - Please note that "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials" library is no more available and is renamed to "ServiceAccountCredentials" according to my search. I am attaching my code below:

```
import json
import os

from httplib2 import Http

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

jsonfile = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'private_key.json')

client_email = 'abce@api-*********-*****.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

json_file = jsonfile

cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_***********'

report_to_download = 'earnings/earnings_201811_*********-*.zip'

private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(client_email, private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')

storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

result = storage.objects().get(bucket =cloud_storage_bucket,object =report_to_download).execute()
print(result)
```

Error i am facing:
[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT3vW.png)

On the other hand, i am able to access data successfully using .net [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65487790/net-google-play-download-sales-reports) , hence there is no rights issue.
And i think there is something wrong with ServiceAccountCredentials parameters, that is why it is unable to make signed jwt.

Other details:
python: 3.9.5
google-cloud-storage: 1.43.0
google-auth: 2.3.3

I know the question got too long, but it would be great if somebody can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error myself by changing
this

```
ServiceAccountCredentials(client_email, private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')
```

to this

```
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')
```

Though error is gone but the result is not what i expected. It returned some kind of metadata of the bucket, for example: timeCreated, storageClass, id and etc.

So, to get my desired result, i changed my approach and wrote another piece of code [here](https://github.com/usereman/g-play-console-report-to-s3-python#google-cloud-storage-bucket-details). This code gets data from google cloud storage to s3 bucket.

I hope this example may help someone in the future.